# Installation doesn't detect existing partitions

Tags: 11.10, partitioning, installation

I am trying to install Ubuntu 11.10 in a dual boot with my existing Windows 7 but the installer does not detect any existing partitions.

I have tried resetting my BCD using EasyBCD and doing fixmbr from the Windows startup disc. A while ago I had to use TestDisk to recover my partition table so this might be the cause but I have installed Ubuntu and Windows many times before with no problems.

fdisk -l output:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 640.1 GB, 640135028736 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 77825 cylinders, total 1250263728 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x360555e5

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048  1250274689   625136321    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Disk /dev/sdf: 7803 MB, 7803174912 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 948 cylinders, total 15240576 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x6f795a8d

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdf1   *          63    15240575     7620256+   c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

Comment: When you boot into the live cd and run disk utility from the dash what does it list for your drive?

Comment: Gparted shows only unallocated space and no partitions if that's what you're asking

Comment: From the live cd can you post the output of `sudo fdisk -l` and edit your question with the result?

Comment: I pasted the fdisk output in the question. I've installed Ubuntu and Windows many times on this hard drive fine but it wasn't until I recovered the partition table using TestDisk has it not been able to see the partitions.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the `fdisk` output you only have one partition on `/dev/sda` and I assume you wish to install Ubuntu there.

Can you boot into either version of Windows installed on the drives? have you created a partition using the Windows built in partition tool?

I would have a VERY GOOD read through the instructions on [this site](http://members.iinet.net.au/~herman546/).

Your best bet is to follow the instructions for Graphical Install B or C - **depending on which you are more comfortable with GParted or the buit in partion tool on the Ubuntu live CD.**

Basically I would boot into the live CD environment and choose the last option 'Something else' and progress from there.

Comment: I only have 1 actual installation of Windows on the hard drive and I can boot into it fine. I haven't created a partition using the Windows tool. Thanks, I'll look into it.

Comment: Your `/dev/sdf` partition looks like it has Windows 95 installed on it - ensure you install GRUB into `/dev/sda` or you will have issues on boot if you do not specify `/dev/sda` as the boot drive....